# How to inverse an integer in C?

Tags: c, hex, inverse

I am trying to inverse a hexadecimal value. The result is wrong, however.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t acc = 0xBBD1;

    printf("0x%X", htons(~acc));    // prints 0x2E44 
}
```

Let's do the inversion by hand:

```
0xBBD1 = 1011 1011 1101 0001
~1011 1011 1101 0001 =
 0100 0100 0010 1110
0100 0100 0010 1110 = 0x442E
```

This means, the code should actually print `0x442E` instead of `0x2E44`.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: have look at bit endianness.

Comment: @cad This is a significant edit you've done.  IMO, it loses some of OP's original issue.

Comment: @chux Why exactly is there a loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, no. But why are you using `htons`? It changes the endianess of a 16 bit datum to big-endian (that is, network byte order). First is your variable not 16 bit but 32 bit, so `uint16_t acc = 0xBBD1` would be more appropriate. Second, as your on a little-endian machine, the bytes are exchanged, hence the output.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about endian until now, I fix my code to take endian into account.

Answer (score 0):

`htons()` reverses the byte order on x86 machines. So your result is correct, just bytes swapped. Have a look at endianness.